# How to get past Thinkpad T530 PXE prompt to BIOS setup?

Tags: windows-7, uefi, thinkpad, pxe

How do I get to the Thinkpad T530 BIOS setup? As the laptop turns on I press `ENTER` when prompted, then press `F1` when prompted, but that takes me to the Intel PXE prompt. If I hit `CTRL-S` I get into the PXE setup menu, but when I exit that (or if I never hit `CTRL-S` in the first place) the computer just sits there and never gets into BIOS setup (and never boots, for that matter).

I know I can get into the BIOS because I did get into it once (only looked around, didn't change anything and definitely did NOT put it into UEFI-only mode). But I don't know/can't remember how to get past the PXE thing. Personally, I'd love to just disable it because I am never going to and don't even want to do remote network boots.

Comment: Have you tried pushing the Thinkvantage Burton at boot?

Comment: On my laptop that just starts the recover-from-the-hidden-partition program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a ThinkPad X230, so the keys may be different, but I have a few ways to get into the BIOS:

- Press <kbd>F1</kbd> at the Lenovo/ThinkPad logo to enter the BIOS.
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the Lenovo/ThinkPad logo.  The `Startup Interrupt Menu` will appear.  Press <kbd>F1</kbd> to enter the BIOS.
- Press <kbd>F12</kbd> at the Lenovo/ThinkPad logo.  A tabbed menu will appear.  Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch from `Boot Menu` to `Application Menu`.  Select the `Setup` option to enter the BIOS.

It sounds like the second method is what you're doing and it doesn't work for you.  How about the other two?